# Linked list in data flow diagram

Tags: linked-list, dataflow-diagram

Is this correct?
What i basically want to ask is that- Is it correct to consider a linked list as a data source.
What happens in this program is that a text files contents are loaded into memory in a linked list. Which does all the processing work and then when the program quits the linked lists are written to the file. In that case is this DFD correct?

[image]

Comment: What is this? What are you trying to do? Please add some additional information to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are asking is rather a Data flow diagram, or also known as dynamic/event view of design.

This diagram tells how on the UI ,events will proceed.

> What i basically want to ask is that- Is it correct to consider a
>   linked list as a data source.

Yes of course, Sometimes it is good to proceed with Link List. LL provides a simpler and faster way to move through nodes having various attributes of a specific entity.

> What happens in this program is that a text files contents are loaded
>   into memory in a linked list.

Basically its not a good idea to store data as text,it increases parsing overhead.The Node values in LL are rather stored in binary format in such a way that when a program loads them, it can quickly link all the interconnected nodes.

> Which does all the processing work and then when the program quits the
>   linked lists are written to the file.

Difficult to understand what you want to ask, but if you are asking who does processing work then obviously its your program who parses the data saved in file.Your program will also dump changes to file if you make any alteration in previous data.

> In that case is this DFD correct?

Hard to tell, untill whole requirement is known..